# Unable to append jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am unable to append the page just seems to refresh where as i want to view it without refreshing the page

**index.php**

```
<div class="view_comment">
        <b>username :</b> <?php echo  $comment_comment;?>
</div> 
<div id="comment_type_area" class="comment_type_area">
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="text" class="comment" post_id="<?php echo $shared_id2; ?>" id="text_comment" placeholder="Write a Comment"></input>
            <input type="submit" id="post_button" ></input> 
        </form>
        </div>
```

**Jquery.js**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.comment').keydown(function (e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13){
                var post_id = $(this).attr('post_id');
                var comment = $(this).val();
                $.post('/comment.php',{ post_id: post_id, comment:comment});
                $('.comment').val('');
/*i am guessing the problem starts from here and onwards*/
                $(this).parent().children('.comments').append("<div class='view_comment'><b>Username :</b>" + comment +"</div>");
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Have you made sure that there is no javascript error throwing into the browser's console?

Comment: well the form does submit because i can see it in my db and also i am able to fetch it form my DB

Comment: and the console doesn't show any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error was in the jquery post i was appending it to `..children('comments').append` which was wrong it should have been like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.comment').keydown(function (e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            e.preventDefault();
            var post_id = $(this).attr('post_id');
            var comment = $(this).val();
            $.post('/comment.php',{ post_id: post_id, comment:comment});
            $('.comment').val('');
            $(this).parent().append("<div class='view_comment'><b>Username :</b>" + comment +"</div>");
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 6):

You should add `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the submit since when you click enter `button` in fields of form that will submit automatically the form :

```
if(e.keyCode == 13){
     e.preventDefault();

     var post_id = $(this).attr('post_id');
     var comment = $(this).val();
     ...
}
```

**Note :** input is one of self-closed tags so it should be `<input type="submit" id="post_button" />`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` helped me to stop reloading page but i am unable to append

Comment: Please try to add the full html to the OP since i can't find any element with class `comments`.

Comment: there is no element as class `comments`

Comment: So why are you trying to append html to it `...children('.comments').append...`.